# Using google places api in android

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I want to use Google places API in android project.But only 1000 requests are allowed in a day.I read somewhere that if i verify with credit card i will be getting 100,000 requests per day.My question is that will i be charged for the 100,000 requests?

I have yet to start the project.Below is some irrelevant code.

```
public void initialiseMap()
    {

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else
        {
            //MapsInitializer.initialize(MainActivity.this);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        //googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
//          UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
//          uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);



            }
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));
        new RetrieveStoreDetails().execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be charged for 1,00,000 requests, credit card details are for authentication purpose only. 
You will be charged only if you cross 1,00,000 requests